# UnReachable code-How to use preprocessor settings

Tags: blackberry, java-me, preprocessor, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Can anyone help me,how to make the preprocessor settings starting from 4.5 OS in Blackberry?

if i use preprocessors such as JDE_4_7 and NOT_JDE_4_5(For eg)I am getting the error as unreachable code,

Is there any condition that we should not use preprocessors in a single location?
How can i rectify it?
[image: Preprocessor Blackberry]

Comment: All of your `#ifdef`s are commented out, looks like.

Comment: Haven't you come across `Alt + Prt Scr` before?

Comment: @Bala R, that's how BlackBerry preprocessor directives are supposed to be written.  Java doesn't have real preprocessor support, so the annotations have to go in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the preprocessor directives in Eclipse?  Meaning, do you expect this code to be reachable with the set of preprocessor directives you are using at the moment?   The Java compiler is not aware of preprocessor directives, so you need to write your code so that the compiler is happy with all the combinations you intend to use.